# Testing REST-API responses with Rspec and Rack::Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, integration-testing

I am a bit stumped. I have the following integration test:

```ruby
require "spec_helper"

describe "/foods", :type => :api do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  let(:current_user) { create_user! }
  let(:host) { "http://www.example.com" }

  before do
    login(current_user)
    @food = FactoryGirl.create_list(:food, 10, :user => current_user)
  end

  context "viewing all foods owned by user" do

    it "as JSON" do
      get "/foods", :format => :json

      foods_json = current_user.foods.to_json
      last_response.body.should eql(foods_json)
      last_response.status.should eql(200)

      foods = JSON.parse(response.body)

      foods.any? do |f|
        f["food"]["user_id"] == current_user.id
      end.should be_true

      foods.any? do |f|
        f["food"]["user_id"] != current_user.id
      end.should be_false
    end

  end

  context "creating a food item" do

    it "returns successful JSON" do
      food_item = FactoryGirl.create(:food, :user => current_user)

      post "/foods.json", :food => food_item

      food = current_user.foods.find_by_id(food_item["id"])
      route = "#{host}/foods/#{food.id}"

      last_response.status.should eql(201)
      last_response.headers["Location"].should eql(route)
      last_response.body.should eql(food.to_json)
    end

  end

end
```

I've added the required Rack::Test::Methods to get me the `last_response` method but it doesn't seem to work right. `last_response` always seems to show me sign_in page even though I've already signed in.

If I remove Rack::Test::Methods `last_response` goes away and I can use `response` instead and I get the current response. Everything seems to works ok.

Why is this? Where is the `response` method coming from? Can I use `response` to get the previous response from the session?

I need to use the `last_response`, or something similar, for

```
last_response.headers["Location"].should eql(route)
```

so that I can match the routes. If it weren't for this I would be set.

Comment: What's the code for `login` - is that an rspec defined method or did you define it somewhere else? Does the login page require a redirect to work? If so put `follow_redirect!` after the login code.

Comment: What is the solution you came up with? I work with the [Ticketee](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee) example as well but still `last_response` does not contain the response I expect? Also, do not forget to mark one of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

`response` is automatic for certain spec types.

Rspec probably mixes `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior` for `:type => :api` blocks.
`response` would come from `ActionController::TestCase::Behavior`, as it does for `:type => :controller` blocks.

If you want to get the response before that given by `response`, try storing it in a variable before you make the next request.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-3/docs/controller-specs and https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails give some information about what is mixed in with some of the various spec types.

Comment: I had the same issue, my specs were not working when I put them in spec/controllers, when I moved the API specs to a separate folder I did not get this error

Answer (score 0):

I think that `login(current_user)` does not work with Rack::Test::Methods. You need a way to authenticate through your API call, perhaps with an authentication token.

`response` is tied to ActionController, which knows about your login. If I am not mistaken, API calls are independent of the Controller, so it doesn't know that you are already logged in.

See [Ticketee](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee/blob/master/spec/api/v3/json/tickets_spec.rb), the example app from [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz/), for an example!