# Rack test fails: No response yet for JSON request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rack-test

I am trying to create a JSON API for my Ruby project following the [Ticketee](https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee) example provided in Yehuda Katz's book [Rails 3 in Action](http://www.manning.com/katz/), chapter 13. Here is an RSpec test described on page 353 adapted to my environment.

```
# /spec/api/v1/farms_spec.rb # Reduced to the minimum code.
require "spec_helper"
include ApiHelper # not sure if I need this

describe "/api/v1/farms", type: :api do
    context "farms viewable by this user" do
        let(:url) { "/api/v1/farms" }
        it "json" do
            get "#{url}.json"
            assert last_response.ok?
        end
    end
end
```

When I run the test I get the following output ...

```
$ rspec spec/api/v1/farms_spec.rb
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
Run options: include {:focus=>true}

All examples were filtered out; ignoring {:focus=>true}
  1) /api/v1/farms farms viewable by this user json
     Failure/Error: assert last_response.ok?
     Rack::Test::Error:
       No response yet. Request a page first.
     # ./spec/api/v1/farms_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 2.29 seconds
1 example, 1 failure
```

Here is the helper module I use ...

```
# /support/api/helper.rb
module ApiHelper
    include Rack::Test::Methods

    def app
        Rails.application
    end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include ApiHelper, type: :api
end
```

**Note**: This question is similar to [Testing REST-API responses with Rspec and Rack::Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292061/testing-rest-api-responses-with-rspec-and-racktest).

Comment: can you post your Gemfile?

Comment: Here is the [Gemfile](http://pastebin.com/TbAWRmKJ) of the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rspec-rails seems to ignore the `type: :api` parameter of the describe block and treats all specs in /spec/api as request specs [(see chapter request specs here)](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails). Maybe the type-parameter is deprecated? I haven't found any documentation for it yet..

I can get your example to work when using `type: :request` instead of `type: :api`. I also removed the app-method as it's already included in the RequestExampleGroup by default.

```
# /support/api/helper.rb
module ApiHelper
    include Rack::Test::Methods
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include ApiHelper, type: :request
end
```

And the spec:

```
#/spec/api/v1/farms_spec.rb 
require "spec_helper"

describe "/api/v1/farms" do
    context "farms viewable by this user" do
        let(:url) { "/api/v1/farms" }
        it "json" do
            get "#{url}.json"
            assert last_response.ok?
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Totally strange. I will stick to your workaround until someone else presents a more suitable solution.

Comment: where is /support/api/helper.rb ? :(